# Sound distortion in headphones

Tags: sound, headphones, quality

I'm new to Ubuntu and the issue that I'm facing is that my left headphones is causing some crackling while listen to music or any audio whether online or offline. I have tried using pulse but the issue is not resolved. The heaphones are working fine with my android deveice and windows pc. Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Unless you tried it in the same PC with a different OS *and* it worked as expected, you have no way of knowing if it is an hardware problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael. It was working fine when my laptop had Windows in it. The problem occured when I switched to Ubuntu. Can it be a driver issue?

Comment: It can be drivers (unlikely) but again "it *was* working fine" means nothing.

Comment: Can you tell me what went wrong?

Comment: I already told what I think the problem is. Unless you try another OS and there it works as it should, everything else points to hardware.

Comment: I already told you it was working fine in Windows..

Comment: And when was that exactly? Yesterday, lest week...?

Comment: I had windows till 17th, and headphones are working fine. on 18th I installed ubuntu and distortions are since then..

Comment: OK, if you say so. But crackling in one channel only being related to software is unheard (the pun was not intended). I'm afraid you will have no answers.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution to this problem https://okubuntu.wordpress.com/2018/02/07/distortions-in-left-earphone/